# 12-bit Computer Discrete Math Conceptual Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

The question about the Duodec-1 computer, manufactured by the Duosomata Computer Corporation. It has 12-bit words and represents integers in two’s-complement form.

Question: Can the Duodec-1 represent an integer $n$ such that $n\neq 0$ and $n = −n$? If your answer is yes, then write $n$ in decimal (base $10$). If your answer is no, then briefly explain why.

Attempted Answer: I said no because if $n = -n$, then the integer wouldn't be in two-complements form. If $n$ did not equal $0$, then there would be the problem of $n = 0$ and $n = -0$, and two's complement form avoids this.

I'm a bit confused on what this question is actually asking.

Comment: Your answer is correct. You may just be confused because they are telling you about a specific computer when the question is really just "Can $n=-n$ in 12 bit twos complement integers if $n\ne 0$"? You could also make your answer more clear by stating that positive integers have a leading 0 and negative integers have a leading 1.

Comment: Consider binary $100000000000$. This should be decimal $2048 = -2048$. But $2048$ overflows $12$ bits as the most significant bit clashes with the sign bit.

Comment: But since it's 13-bit, it can't be represented on the computer anyway.

Comment: Decimal $2048$ fits in $12$ bits, as does $-2048$. The difference lies in the intepretation of the most-significant bit.

Comment: @AxelKemper the question specifically mentions twos complement representation. In twos complement the leading bit is interpreted as a sign bit so you cannot have both $2048$ and $-2048$.